# ¿Es obligatorio poner el tipo genérico en la herencia?

Tags: java, herencia, genericos

Estoy practicando la genericidad y me he topado con que esté código:

```
public class prueba<E> {
    E i;
    public prueba(E i){
       this.i = i;
    }
}
public class prueba2<E> extends prueba<E>{
   public prueba2(E i){
      super(i);
   }
}
```

Funciona igual que este:

```
public class prueba<E> {
        Integer i;
        public prueba(Integer i){
            this.i = i;
        }
        
    }
public class prueba2<E> extends prueba{
   public prueba2(E i){
      super(i);
   }
}
```

Como se puede ver, en la clase `prueba2` la parte del `extends` se puede quitar `<E>` y funciona igual ¿Es aconsejable poner la `<E>` aunque sea por normas de estilo?

Comment: no soy experto en java.. pero ese generico de arriba, no suena muy genercio.. si no usas E.. para que esta E??? donde es generico?? lo segundo no tengo ni idea... a los de java les gustan las cosas verborragicas...

Comment: en este caso no tiene sentido usar el genérico, quien te hizo el ejemplo es un idiota. Ahora que si cambiaras el tipo de i por E la cosa ya se pone interesante. Y respondiendo a tu pregunta... si no se lo pones y compila... no es obligatorio.

Comment: Funciona igual porque no estás usando `E` para nada. El segundo caso extiende de un [*Raw Type*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html)

Comment: @RuslanLópez he hecho lo que has dicho de poner la i como genérica (he editado la pregunta con la corrección) y no ha cambiado nada, sigue pasando lo mismo así que supongo que a java le dará igual.